# C++: Calling a specific funtion within a class via the main function

Tags: c++, function

I have 3 classes and each has a function within them, **I want to call these functions specifically via a number-driven menu from within the main function.** For example, if the user chooses *New accounts* I want to redirect him to the *New accounts function*. What I wanna know is how can you exactly call a specific function (within a class) from the main function. Thereby, please let me know whether what I have tried below is correct and if not how I can correct it!
Thanks!

*"account" is the name of the class and "newAccount" is the name of the function*

```cpp
cout << "... Please choose one\n 1.New account\n 2.Withdraw\n 3.Loan\n Input:";
cin >> menu_input;
if (menu_input==1) {
  cout << "You have Choosen Accounts...";
  account.newAccount();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct and widely used. For 3 functions/methods (and more) a `switch` would be a bit more convenient:

```
switch(menu_input)
{
case 1:
    account.newAccount();
    break;
case 2:
    other.method();
    break;
case 3:
    yet_another.method();
    break;
}
```

PS: `account.newAccount()` sounds and looks like a weird concept. And please don't put closing braces at the end of a line with another expression, instead:

```
if(condition) {
    do_something();
}
```

or (my preference):

```
if(condition)
{
    do_something();
}
```

### Edit:

I missed that you said

> "account" is the name of the class and "newAccount" is the name of the
> function

If you want to call a **method** (or "member function") of a class, you have to instantiate that class (create an object of that class) before using it:

```
Account account;
account.newAccount(); // that sounds wrong
```

or make that method static (which is probably what you want here, considering the name of that method):

```
class Account
{
    ...
    static Account newAccount() {...}
    ...
};

int main()
{
    ...
    auto account = Account::newAccount();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! If I am using a switch can I use something similar to an elsewhere if the inputs are not matched by any condition I can go ahead and display a message telling that the response is invalid and I can ask the user to input a new input etc.

Comment: yes with the `default:` case which is used if no other case matched. You would probably have to put your whole `switch` inside a `while` loop or something to jump back to the beginning if you didn't get a valid input.

Comment: Got it, yes I am planning to embed the whole switch inside a loop!

Comment: But read about classes and objects. You seem to have missed some parts of that topic.

Comment: I'm not sure OP asked for code style guidance.

Comment: @tilz0R No OP didn't ask for style guidance, but brace placement in the shown code is more than unusual and makes reading code a little harder. It's hard to draw a line between "just style" and "readability" and it doesn't bloat the answer to point it out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you have to declare an instance of the account class and use it in your code. For example:

```
account accountInstance;

cin>> menu_input;
if (menu_input==1){
    Cout<<"You have Choosen Accounts...";
    accountInstance.newAccount();}
```

If the newAccount() method is to be a static method, you do not need to declare an instance for the class, but you should use it this way:

```
cin>> menu_input;
if (menu_input==1){
   Cout<<"You have Choosen Accounts...";
   account::newAccount();}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I am not really sure e whether I understand what you mean by "you have to declare an instance of the account class and use it in your code"